# While trying to restore pgbackups in rails by writing- "heroku pg:backups restore 'URL' DATABASE -a appname". It does not deploy my database to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Command:
$ heroku pg:backups restore 'URL' DATABASE -a appname

!    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: appname
 !    To proceed, type "appname" or re-run this command with --confirm appname

> appname

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup
will continue restoring. Use heroku pg:backups to check progress.
Stop a running restore with heroku pg:backups cancel.

r011 ---restore---> HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK
←[0KAn error occurred and your backup did not finish.
Please run `heroku pg:backups info r011` for details.

After I Ran the above command, then:

$ heroku pg:backups info r011

=== Backup info: r011

Database:    BACKUP

Started:     2015-07-09 19:01:23 +0000

Finished:    2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000

Status:      Failed

Type:        Manual

Backup Size: 0.00B

=== Backup Logs

2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000: 2015/07/09 19:01:24 aborting: could not write to outp
ut stream: Expected HTTP Status 200, received: "403 Forbidden"

2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000: waiting for restore to complete

2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000: pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from inp
ut file: end of file

2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000: restore done

2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000: waiting for download to complete

2015-07-09 19:01:24 +0000: download done

Comment: Anyone got any solution?